# Delete records before sysdate

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to delete all the records before sysdate. This is my query:

```
DELETE from ANNOUNCEMENT_TABLE
WHERE ANNOUNCEMENT_DATE != SYSDATE
```

But it is deleting all the records from database. How can I do this properly?

Comment: `!=` means "not the same", not "before" - I think you want `<`

Comment: Also, do you have SYSDATE defined anywhere?

Comment: @BLaZuRE sysdate is built-in - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions172.htm

Answer (score 3):

```
DELETE FROM ANNOUNCEMENT_TABLE
WHERE ANNOUNCEMENT_DATE < TRUNC(SYSDATE);
```

Comment: what is results from  `select count(*), max(announcement_date) from announcement_table`.

Comment: COUNT(*) MAX(ANNOU
---------- ---------
         3 06-JUN-13

Comment: @user2458277  May be you need to use `< trunc(sysdate)` rather than `< sysdate` because `sysdate` alone means "current moment in time", not "current date". With `trunc()` applied you get the moment in time, corresponding to the start of the current day.

Answer (score -2):

Delete from announcement_table
where announcement_date <> sysdate;
or
Delete from announcement_table
where announcement_date